# Basic calculation issue

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, arithmetic

So this problem seems rather elementary however I can't reach the solution given in my notes so I was hoping someone here may be able to enlighten me. (I'm finding confidence intervals for Survival Analysis)

[image]

So the mathematics I am completely fine with however I can't match the given solution above, i've tried doing it by hand and by using R here is my output when using R

(log(-log(0.368)) + 1.96*(8/33)^(0.5))/abs(log(0.368))

0.9650258

and repeating this with the minus gives:

(log(-log(0.368)) - 1.96*(8/33)^(0.5))/abs(log(0.368))

-0.9656814

I note that my answers are (pretty) close but obviously there's an error either in the given solutions or in mine

Am I stupid? Am I missing something painfully obvious? Is there an error in the given answers would appreciate any help!

Comment: How do you get 8/33. That doesn't match what is in the brackets above does it?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your solution:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{3 \times 4} + \ldots +\frac1{9 \times 10} +\frac1{10 \times 11} &=\sum_{n=3}^{10} \frac1{n (n+1)}\\
&=\sum_{n=3}^{10} \left[\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1} \right]\\
&=\frac13-\frac1{11}\\
&=\frac{8}{33}
\end{align}

$$\ln(-\ln(0.368))+1.96\sqrt{\frac{8}{33}}\frac1{|\ln(0.368)|} \approx 0.9651$$